# Retrieve Groups from OU

Tags: powershell, server, active-directory

What is the correct command to execute and retrieve Groups with specification ._RDP (Named - inside OU) on the end?

I Would like to receive all Group names from OU e.g  SL_FS_xx_RDP.

That is Parent OU:

> OU=Server Admins,OU=Administrative,DC=abcdef,DC=ab

What I've done:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Searchbase 'OU=Server Admins,OU=Administrative,DC=abcdef,DC=ab' -SearchScope OneLevel -Filter * .RDP*
```

is not working

Comment: Could you edit the question to make it more clear what you actually want to achieve? Also, what have you tried so far? Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: In one part of the question you say you want to retrieve OUs. In another part you say you want to get Groups. Which do you want?

Comment: Also first you want to filter for `RDP` and then for `SL`? Please try to edit the question once more

Comment: would like to retrieve the last source names of groups inside the OU. Presented parent . Think was completed clearer and transparently right now

Comment: Nope. It is far from clear.

Comment: What does "last source names" mean? Just the name of the group?

Comment: u have in AD tree - DC under Ou and sub OU when you click on that you have name and type of the group - this what i want to retrieve

Comment: What does "last source names" mean? Just the name of the group? – YES

Comment: Get-ADOrganizationalUnit "OU=Server Admins,OU=Administrative,DC=abcdef,DC=ab"|Format-Table Name                                         it seems that works. but need retrieve property OU - group names (collected inside group)

Answer (score 1):

Still a bit unclear what you want actually.. *need retrieve property OU* seems redundant because you are already giving it the complete OU in the SearchBase parameter..

However, if i understand you correctly, you would like to get the names of group items within a certain OU that have '_RDP' in their name.

You could do that like so:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like '*_RDP*'} -Searchbase 'OU=Server Admins,OU=Administrative,DC=abcdef,DC=ab' -SearchScope OneLevel | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

or

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(name=*_RDP*)" -Searchbase 'OU=Server Admins,OU=Administrative,DC=abcdef,DC=ab' -SearchScope OneLevel | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

If what you need from these group(s) is more than just the name, remove the `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` part and just do a `| ForEach-Object {...}`. Also you can use the `-Properties` switch on the Get-ADGroup cmdlet to feed it with all the properties you are after.

Comment: Thx Theo, don't know why but noticed that used wrong cmdlet ...should be get -AdGroup instead of ADOrganizationalunit. Probably that is the answer on my question will check it out soon. thx